# Crimp-on wire splitter?

Tags: connector

This little cramp on connector is something similar to butt connector, but has extra leg, i.e. like 3 way butt connector.

I want to take existing wire and attach to it, or connect to it in paralel without tools. I imaginee it would be something I would take with pliers and crimp on it and it would give me extra wire out of it without soldering.

Is there any specific name for this kind of connector?

Comment: Can you post a picture of that connector?

Answer (score 12):

You are looking for a connector that looks like this:

[image]

Here is a [distributor web link](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?SKU=46F4357&CMP=KNC-GPLA) where these can be purchased.

Comment: Noooooo, scotchloks are a horrid thing, don't do it!

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative.

Take a connector bar and a copper bus bar.
connect 3 of connector bar poles to to copper bus bar at one side.
Use other side 3 poles to connect your wires.

I don't know how much my setup is comply with FCC standards. May be olin or
steven could bug me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's [this one](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0191640011_SPLICES.xml).

[image]

You can also make an assembly like that with 3x ring terminals and a screw.

Could you describe your wiring a little bit more?  What wire gauge(s) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any specific name for this kind of connector?

The connector (and as shown in the diagram posted by Michael Karas) is called a Scotchlok connector [3M UK's website](http://solutions.3m.co.uk/wps/portal/3M/en_GB/ElectricalMkts/ElectricalSupplies/products/scotchlok-wire-connectors/scotchlok-electrical-idc-wire-connectors/scotchlok-560b-run-tap-connector/)

Answer (score 0):

Generically these may be called "taps". Frequently used for car and other vehicle aftermarket electronics installations.

Here's one that does not require tools (assuming you've got the new wire stripped), from [this](https://www.crutchfield.ca/p_669PP605/Posi-Products-Wire-Connectors.html?awkw=294898723662&awat=pla&awnw=g&awcr=190578129978&awdv=c&awug=9000815) website:

[image]